# How to get the distinct field value in a multiple field in multiple table?

Tags: mysql, database, distinct

i have a two table x and y.  In that x table has x1 as country, x2 as country, y table has y1 as country, y2 has country.  For this data, how can i get the distinct country values in this two table with this four country field?

Before that i used a single country in a single table like this,

```
$query="select distinct(`x1`) from x";
```

Now, i have the take distinct values in this two table as well as from four country values.  For this union is possible.  But i need any solution used in a single query without union concept.

Please provide the idea for this.  Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Why can you not use `UNION`? Can you give an example of your existing data, and what you want to return?

Comment: @Mike i used and get the solution in union, apart from union i asked the solution for any other alternative or simple method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea: use [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/union.html)

Comment: at the time of writing that wasn't specified :P will think of an alternative

Answer (score 1):

not the most efficient query ever, but try this:

```
SELECT `x1` FROM x
UNION 
SELECT `x2` FROM x
UNION 
SELECT `y1` FROM y
UNION 
SELECT `y2` FROM y
```

Comment: @KM: `UNION` returns distinct results, so there's no need for the `DISTINCT` in each `SELECT`.

Comment: @Karthik, UNION is the way to do this, anything else will be more complicated, why can't you use UNION?

Answer (score 1):

Union is the best answer to this question, as that's exactly what it's designed for.

The only other method I can think of would be a full outer join - something like:

```
select coalesce(cx.country,cy.country) country 
from (select distinct country from x) cx
full outer join (select distinct country from y) cy 
on cx.country = cy.country
```

However, you can't do full outer joins in MYSQL (as far as I know) - and the workarounds involve unions...